# Filling in the blank

Tags: word-choice

There is this sentence I wrote, yet I am struggling to find a fitting word for it to be complete.
The sentence is Family is the solid foundation on which the .... of society rests

Comment: What do you need the word to mean?

Comment: I am not really sure but perhaps structure

Comment: In the essay introduction, I wrote: Family is the solid foundation on which the ..... of society rests. Thus, a healthy family contributes to a healthier community.

Answer (score 1):

A frequent phrase to convey this meaning is "X is the backbone of Y," so you could say "Family is the backbone of society." You could also simply say "Family is the foundation of society." Both of these simply state that family is integral to society's existence.

In the sentence "Family is the solid foundation on which the _ of society rests," the _ should be filled with an aspect of society that family is protecting. If you have a singular aspect of society that you believe family is specifically beneficial for, put it there. You could say "on which the structure of society rests," which could have two meanings: Either that the organizational structure of the way society is made up starts with the family, *or* it continues the metaphor started by "family is the solid foundation." The metaphor of "solid foundation" references the foundation of a building, so "structure," being a synonym for building, compliments the metaphor. However, because "structure" merely continues the "foundation" metaphor, you are using many words to say very little. You could simply say "Family is the foundation of society" and it would have the same meaning.

I don't want to give you many more examples, because this sentence introduces the idea behind your argument, so without knowing that I can't tell you what you should put there, but you could say something like "Family is the solid foundation on which the moral fiber of society rests." In this case, you are arguing that the family unit causes a moral society, and without the family society would be immoral. I would think about what you are trying to say in your essay, and pick one of the reasons family is important to society to fill in the blank.